# A possible proof about properties of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, fake-proofs

I have the following proposition to prove:

**Proposition (1)** Let $A:=\{\vec{v}_1,...,\vec{v}_n\}$ be a subset of an $F$-vectorial space $V$. If $\text{span}(A)=V$ then every subset of $V$ independient in $V$ has a cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of $A$.

This is the proof I found:

*Proof.* Suppouse exists a subset $B:=\{\vec{b}_1,...,\vec{b}_m\}$ of $V$ independient in $V$ such that $\text{card}(B)>\text{card}(A)$, I mean, $m>n$. $\text{span}(A)=V$ if and only if every vector in $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $A$, so
$$\mathbf{A}:=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & ... & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\\
\vdots\\
\vec{v}_n
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{e}_1\\
\vdots\\
\vec{e}_n
\end{bmatrix}$$
has solution for all $\vec{e}_1,...,\vec{e}_n\in V$ and in consequence $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible.  Let $\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & ... & c_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
c_{n1} & ... & c_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$. Then
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\\
\vdots\\
\vec{v}_n
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & ... & c_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
c_{n1} & ... & c_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{b}_1\\
\vdots\\
\vec{b}_n
\end{bmatrix}$$
so each vector in $A$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\vec{b}_1,...,\vec{b}_n$. But we have that $\vec{b}_{n+1}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vector of $A$, and each ocurrence of vector of $A$ in such linear combination can be replaced by a linear combination of $\vec{b}_1,...,\vec{b}_n$, then $\vec{b}_{n+1}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\vec{b}_1,...,\vec{b}_n$, but this implies that $B$ is not independiente in $V$, and this is absurd.                                                 $\blacksquare$

I want to know if is this proof is right, can anyone help me?
If I am wrong please don't tell me where I am wrong, just tell me I am wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: The equation $$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & ... & a_{1n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & ... & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{v}_1\\
\vdots\\
\vec{v}_n
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{e}_1\\
\vdots\\
\vec{e}_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not well formed in the context of (introductory) linear algebra. The entries of a column vector must be numbers, not vectors from an unspecified vector space $V$.

Comment: Also, the sentence "[equation] has solution for all $\vec{e}_1,...,\vec{e}_n\in V$ and in consequence $\mathbf{A}$ is invertible" only makes sense if $\mathbf A$ is a specific matrix. However, the $\mathbf A$ required depends, in principle, on the vectors $\vec{e}_1,...,\vec{e}_n$.

Comment: I understand you asked not to be told where you are wrong, but this is not a case of an incorrect deduction, rather the statements that you wrote are uninterpretable (and hence "not even wrong").